# C++ anonymous class initialization

Tags: c++

is it possible to initialize member variables in anonymous class?

for example

```
class {
public: int &value;
} container;
```

Comment: Why do you want an anonymous class (That would never get through code review). What about an unnamed namespace that means the class name would not leak into another CU.

Comment: @Martin York  function local containers/functors

Comment: That's not a `class`, it's a `struct`.

Comment: @sbi: Aside from obviating the "public:", does that make any difference to the question?

Comment: @Fred: it must be an aggregate (slightly looser than POD), which `class` es very rarely are. It would be illegal to have any nonstatic nonpublic members.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Rare by convention, yes.  But in fact a `class` might be an aggregate and a `struct` might not be an aggregate.

Comment: @Fred: To me, a `class` represents a certain level of abstraction. Something that has nothing but (or little more than) public data members (or, worse, getters/setters) is merely a conglomerate of data - which is exactly what `struct` was invented for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
int x = 3;
class {
    public: int &value;
} container = {x};
```

Comment: doh.  so obvious in retrospect

Comment: +1 because I didn't realize an aggregate can contain a reference. But, just to point out, this does require an aggregate. (The only requirements that actually apply are no access control and no bases.)