# Is it possible to use anonymous classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, g++, c++14

I have seen **anonymous classes** in `C++` code on Quora. It's successfully compiled and run.

**Code here:**

```
#include <iostream>

auto func()
{
    class // no name
    {
      public:
             int val;
    } a;

    a.val = 5;

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func().val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, **Is it valid in C++?**

Also, I am curious to know, **Is it possible to use anonymous classes in C++?**

Comment: It's kinda been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612164/c-anonymous-class-initialization)

Comment: C++ has [anonymous unions](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union.anon), but no anonymous classes/structs, which some compilers provide as an extension. Still, unnamed classes as shown in the question are valid.

Comment: @cpplearner an anonymius union is a class *member* of a union type which has no name (the member, not the type).

Comment: @n.m usually an "anonymous" class/union means such that has both no name, but also no object instantiated. Its members become members of the enclosing class scope or function's block scope. An unnamed class simply means there's no name, but otherwise it's a usual class with an object declared immediately. C++ doesn't have anonymous classes, but anonymous unions.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I just looked it up in the standard and it says that an anonymous union is a particular form of a union that defines an unnamed object of an unnamed type. I was wrong assuming it can only be a member of another class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C++, an *anonymous union* is a union of this form:

```
 union { ... } ;
```

It defines an unnamed object of an unnamed type. Its members are injected in the surrounding scope, so one can refer to them without using an `<object>.` prefix that otherwise would be necessary.

In this sense, no anonymous classes (that are not unions --- in C++ unions are classes) exist.

On the other hand, unnamed classes (including structs and unions) are nothing unusual.

```
union { ... } x;
class { ... } y;
typedef struct { ... } z;
```

`x` and `y` are named object of unnamed types. `z` is a typedef-name that is an alias for an unnamed struct. They are not called anonymous because this term is reserved for the above form of a union.

```
[](){}
```

Lambdas are unnamed objects of unnamed class types, but they are not called anonymous either.

Comment: Aren't lambdas of type `std::function`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck no, they are convertible to std::function but each lambda has its own unique type.

Comment: @DonaldDuck No, they have an implementation defined type. `std::function` uses type-erasure to bind to any class/function which can be called like a function, i.e. a function object, like a lambda for example.

Answer (score 32):

Not only that, you can create more instances of the class by using `decltype`.

```
#include <iostream>

class 
{
   public:
      int val;
} a;


int main()
{
   decltype(a) b;
   a.val = 10;
   b.val = 20;

   std::cout << a.val << std::endl;
   std::cout << b.val << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
20
```

Comment: Is it true that before C++11 there was no way to do declare another instance of an unnamed class?

Comment: @lisyarus: It was possible with a template like `template <typename T> T create(const T& prototype) { return T(); }`

Comment: @AlexandreC. But how do I assign the result of `create` to a local variable if I don't have access to the type (outside of `create`)?

Comment: I don't think it was possible before C++11, because you couldn't pass such objects to templates (types had to have external linkage). I could be misremembering though. The above code, which declares `a` at namespace scope, would be ill-formed in C++03, because objects with linkage (`a` has external linkage) require types with linkage, but the type has no linkage. I believe that C++11 changed rules here, but again I'm not completely certain.

Comment: @lisyarus That is known as moving the goalposts!  `template<typename T> void create(const T& prototype) { T t; }` creates a local variable of type matching an anonymous type.

Comment: @Yakk I mean declaring an instance of an unnamed class in the same scope as the class declaration.

Answer (score 10):

It was always possible to write something like this:

```
typedef struct { int a; } type;
```

Now, if you look at `struct { int a }` part, this is an anonymous struct. In C++, there's basically no difference between structs and classes (Except the default access modifiers). So, it's possible to have anonymous structs/classes.